# List description between list name and items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting

Is it somehow possible to add a description between list name and items? Maybe with JSON?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible using SharePoint online modern experience default functionalities to add list description in list view as per your requirements.

---

You maybe able to do it using JSON view formatting. But, you have to customize the complete list view and you will lose SharePoint default list view functionalities. *I don't recommend doing this because you only want to add description in list view*.

Check below threads for detailed information:

1. [Change column name in view using json view formatting](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286588/change-column-name-in-view-using-json-view-formatting/286590#286590)
2. [SharePoint Modern List - Change fill color of column headers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303892/sharepoint-modern-list-change-fill-color-of-column-headers/303893#303893)
3. [JSON to format SharePoint List items under a Header](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303941/json-to-format-sharepoint-list-items-under-a-header/303943#303943)

**Note**: Customizing list view using above JSON formatting method removes the standard features such as menus, sorting, moving, resizing, etc. In addition, the sticky header feature is now gone.

Comment: Thank you that helped!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped you!